# How to build a class variable after validation based on the parsed input using pydantic V2?

Tags: python, pydantic-v2

Let's say I have a pydantic class that has two fields that should be provided when creating an instance. Now, I want a third field to be created based on the values of the two arguments passed when instantiating. However, the third field must not be part of the signature, yet it should be available after instantiating as one of the object's attributes, at best not as a PrivateAttr with an underscore before.

In case of a 'ordinary' class this is pretty much straightforward:

```
class MyClass():

    __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
        self.baz = foo * bar
```

However this can't be done the same way with pydantic classes:

```
class MyClass(BaseModel):
    foo: int
    bar: int
    baz: int = foo * bar
```

In my actual case I want to write a class named 'Thermopotentiostat' that does some molecular dynamics simulation. The input is going to be system parameters and the ideal behavior would be that the class constructs an ase.atoms object called system from these parameters, when creating an instance such that I can use it as self.system. I was thinking of achieving it by using a validator with mode = 'after', but still it didn't work as desired.

Actually, I feel like asking a pretty dump question, but I simply couldn't find any satisfactory answer. Probably you have a good suggestion on what I could do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, its like data classes and you have to pre-compute it, before building the whole object. The `pre=True` argument ensures that the validator runs before any other validation, and `always=True` ensures that the validator is run even if the field is not explicitly set. So, what you can do is the following:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class MyClass(BaseModel):
    foo: int
    bar: int
    baz: int

    @validator("baz", pre=True, always=True)
    def set_baz(cls, v, values):
        # Calculate baz based on foo and bar
        return values.get("foo", 0) * values.get("bar", 0)

# Example usage
data = {"foo": 2, "bar": 3}
my_instance = MyClass(**data)
print(my_instance)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Actually, this is what chatgpt told me to do. However, chatgpt's suggestion as well as the code you provided seems to be based on pydantic V1. Unfortunately, in V2 this doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I missed your version, thanks for telling.